# primary ideals in principal ideals domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I'm to prove that an ideal $M$ is primary iff for some $n$, $M = (p^n)$ where $p$ is a prime or $p=0$.

The second direction is simply proved referring to the definition of the primary ideal, my problem is in the first direction starting that $M$ is a primary ideal.

I have no idea to conclude that my ideal have to be generated by $p ^ n$.

Shall anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$M=(a)$ for some $a\in R$ of course. Now suppose that $a$ has two distinct prime divisors. Can you use this to produce two nonzero elements $x,y$ such that $xy\in (a)$, and yet no powers of $x$ and no powers of $y$ are in $(a)$?

If you're having trouble with that hint, just try looking at what happens in $(pq)$ when $p,q$ are distinct primes.

Comment: I'm sorry to till u both hints are abstract can't deduce anything from them :(

Comment: will u simplify it much more please?

Comment: @Enas I don't think it's possible to make it simpler. The second hint is just a toy exmaple of what you need to do in the first hint. Look at $\Bbb Z$ and $(2)$,$(3)$ and $(6)$. Are any powers of $2$ or $3$ in $(6)$?

Comment: so im gonna argue the case if M was generated by a composite number , which wont lead to a primary ideal. That is to be primary it must be generated by a prime or a power if it. Aha i finally got it. Thank u :)

Comment: @Enas Right, well, sort of. Composite is the wrong thing to say. If I understand correctly, you already proved that $(p^n)$ is primary if $p$ is prime. Then you could finish up by showing that if $a$ isn't a prime power, then $(a)$ is not primary. That's proving "A implies B" and "not A implies not B", and that shows "A iff B"

Comment: Aha u mean the contrapositive not A implies not B,  im gonna do so :) thanks again.